# need Redmine plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I`m using Redmine for work in my company and I need some solutions (plugins) for:

1. Advanced email config (user must have ability to mail when status changes and when assigned user changes)
2. Fetch email and create ticket
3. When ticket is closed should automatically change work progress to 100% done and change due date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fetch email and create ticket**

Simple methods for fetching E-Mails an create Tickets direct included in Redmine.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails

when you need more options this plugin give you customer support, E-Mail notifications and many more.

http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/helpdesk

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Stealth Mode plugin could be used to help satisfy your first requirement.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/PluginRedmineStealth
https://github.com/teleological/redmine-stealth-plugin

It requires the user performing the edit to remember to enable stealth mode first.  (And they need to remember to disable it afterward!)